# Повтор части таблицы на всех страницах

Tags: php, шаблоны, html

Есть шаблон документа Накладной с таблицей и итоговым блоком. Нужно чтобы шапка таблицы и ее подвал (итоговый блок) повторялись на каждой странице в независимости от того сколько страниц в документе. Возможно ли это сделать через div на php и как?

Answer (score 1):

если контент в таблице подгружается динамически то можно вынести шапку и подвал в разные файлы php, вставить их с помощью include(), и меняйте только body таблицы (основной контент) через определенный php сценарий, который у вас там есть.... Например так:

`<? include "файл-шапка.php" ?>
<? тут скрипт для вывода основного контента ?>
<? include "файл-подвал.php" ?>`

Comment: только `<?php //blablabla ?>` а не `<? ?>`

Comment: @Naumov согласен, так будет правильней, но и вариант с короткими тегами тоже возможен, если включена поддержка таковых на сервере (а она, по-моему, в большинстве случаев включена)

Comment: Она по умолчанию выключена по этому доставляет много боли вроде всё без ошибок, а где то что отвалилось.